# Timer that reduces by a button

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am making an app that has a feature involving a timer. I want to make a timer that decreases from 50 seconds, but when you press a button the timer restarts again but from 49 seconds.

So for example, if I have tapped the button 10 times, the timer restarts at 40 seconds.

How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Counterlabel: UILabel!
var Nbr2 = 51
var timer2 = NSTimer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func Btn1(sender: AnyObject) {

    Nbr = 51

func Counter(){
    Nbr -= 1

    Counterlabel.text = "\(Nbr)"   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be the answer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Counterlabel: UILabel!
    var Nbr = 51
    var timerValue = 52
    var timer2 = NSTimer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func Btn1(sender: AnyObject) {

        Nbr = timerValue - 1
        timerValue = timerValue - 1;
    }
    func Counter(){
        Nbr -= 1

        Counterlabel.text = "\(Nbr)"
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is working, but what I am trying to acompich is to get the timer to restart but with one second less everytime i tap the bytton, but thanks anyway:)

Comment: Oh alright I edited the answer now so it is working as you wanted :)

Comment: Sure, Do you know how to add a function when ever the time hits 0?:)

Comment: I would check variable Nbr in Counter method and add a method if Nb == 0.